# What is the purple hue around enemy armies in Total War: Warhammer?

Tags: warhammer-total-war

Sometimes when I defeat an enemy army, the campaign map shows a purple aura around the defeated army. What does it mean? I don't recognize it from previous Total War games.

It should be noted that I am playing with the Wood Elves DLC, as well as some mods. The most sizeable one being [Radious' overhaul of the game](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=689913357).

[image: Purple hue]

Comment: Never seen that in over 300 hours. Maybe it's caused by a mod? Did you encounter this with all mods turned off?

Comment: @Artery I added a paragraph about mods/DLC.

Comment: It's still pretty vague without a full list of the mods you are using.
Furthermore, did you try to encounter this with all mods deactivated?

Comment: Its not a mod, I've seen it myself on pure game, usually around chaos/beastmen - I believe its just a pure cosmetic effect of enemy heroes aura.

Answer (score 1):

That purple hue is just a cosmetic thing that happen when you won a battle. This happen to me only with Chaos (playing with him and won versus Kislev and killing Sarthorael with Chaos too), Bordeleaux (just autoresolve the battle versus Red Horns) and also with Clan Angrund (versus Greenskin).

Also, when you won a battle versus Sarthorael, no matter if you are Chaos or another faction, in the campaign map, littles purple tentacles appear.

[image: tentacles]

There are different cosmetic things on the campaign map.